# Magento Transactional Email Logo and HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: magento, email, ssl, https

In Magento CE 1.8, it appears {{var logo_url}} defaults to using an HTTPS link in its transactional emails (if SSL enabled).  This causes an issue in Outlook, because Outlook will not display images with an SSL URL.

Is there any "easy" way to force {{var logo_url}} to HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to enforce anything to be HTTP instead of HTTPS but well... The easiest way I can think of would be to extend `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Abstract` in a own extension (better) or to overwrite it in your local code pool (faster and okay but not so clean) and adapt the function `_addEmailVariables($variables, $storeId)`.

For the sake for demonstration I'll show the second approach:

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php` and create any folders which don't exist already in `app/code/local/`.

Now in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php` in the function `_addEmailVariables($variables, $storeId)` look for

```
if (!isset($variables['logo_url'])) {
    $variables['logo_url'] = $this->_getLogoUrl($storeId);
}
```

and replace it with something like this

```
    if (!isset($variables['logo_url'])) {
        $variables['logo_url'] = str_replace("https", "http", $this->_getLogoUrl($storeId));
    }
```

Not tested but this should work. You can adapt this approach in an own extension as well. Check out the excellent articles on http://inchoo.net/ if you are not familiar with the proccess (http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/ is a good starting point).